# How long will Google Search take to recognize that a website is now mobile-friendly?

Tags: seo, google-search, responsive-webdesign, google-pagespeed, bootstrap

I updated a client's website 3 weeks ago to use Bootstrap. Since then I've run almost every other day Google's Mobile-Friendly test and also Google's PageSpeed, and all results are in the green.

Since then the Mobile Usability report in Google's Webmaster Tools reduced the number of pages with issues from ~70 to 13, and is going down steadily, yet in Google's search results under the website, it still shows "Your website is not mobile-friendy".

Any estimations on how log this will take?

Comment: Mobile friendly is determined page by page. Each page has to be fetched before that page is marked mobile friendly. I have not seen the warning you are getting and have no idea what triggers there are for the warning. I assume that if enough pages are marked mobile friendly, then the message goes away. To be clear, sites are not marked mobile friendly, pages are. Cheers!!

Comment: It is not a warning, it is merely a notice link in google results under the websites I have added to webmaster tools. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Anytime! It will take a while, meanwhile, for the pages marked as mobile friendly, they will perform as you expect. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

It generally takes Google 2 to 4 weeks to make changes in the search results when Googlebot first has to crawl your site to notice the changes.

Since it has been three weeks already, I would expect changes soon.

Comment: there are still some links in the google results where the message still appears. but in most part yes, it seems slowly to go away link by link.

Answer (score 1):

I changed 3 of my websites to support mobile on November 5, more than 2 months ago. I've also used search console to push crawl of mobile version but still see:

> Your page is not mobile-friendly.

in search results. (Google mobile friendly test tool reports that it's fine.)

And my websites has nearly 3000 daily visits. So I was hoping that it would take less time.

Answer (score 0):

Google is taking longer to index some changes. To help on it you can use alternatives indexers that will try to force the reindexation at google, like speed-links for example. External links and social presence can also help to speed up the process (Google+, Facebook, Twitter). And of course crawl as google in Search Console will also help.